# I created an api method using java i wanted to use it in my talend intergration but i dont know how to put the method in talend to use

Tags: java, sql, talend

I created this code for me to get the postal code of the address i wanted and i wanted to have this function in talend for me to use where i would get these three fields for each row and then get the postal code for that address but i can't find out how to insert this code

```
public class postalCodeGetter {



    public static void main(String [] args){
        System.out.println(getPostal("221b", "baker street", "London"));
    }

    public static String getPostal(String streetNum, String streetName, String city){
        if (streetNum == null || streetName == null || city == null){
            return "NA";
        }
        try {
        streetName.replaceAll(" ", "%20");
        URL url = new URL("https://geocoder.ca/?locate=" + streetNum +
                "%20" + streetName + "%20" + city + "%20ON&geoit=XML&json=1");

        HttpURLConnection conn =(HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();

            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");

        conn.connect();

        int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

        if(responseCode!=200){
            throw new RuntimeException("HttpResponse Code: " + responseCode);

        } else {
            StringBuilder informationString = new StringBuilder();

            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(url.openStream());

            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                informationString.append(scanner.nextLine());
            }

            scanner.close();


            if (informationString.toString().isEmpty()){
                return "Address not found";
            }

            String[] ar = informationString.toString().split(", ");
            String postal = "";
            for (String a: ar) {
                if(a.contains("\"postal\"")){
                    postal = a.substring(14, 20);
                }
            }


            return postal;
        }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to create a custom routine as follows.

1. in the repository panel of the Studio, right-click \Code\Routines and select Create routine. The name of the routine has to be the name of your class, postalCodeGetter in your case.
2. copy your code, add the required imports and save the routine.

To use the method of your class in your Talend jobs, insert a tJavaRow component in your flow.  In its Advanced Parameters, add `import routines.postalCodeGetter;`. The code of the tJavaRow component can now contain a call to postalCodeGetter.getPostal().  You can pass column values as parameters to your method, for instance `postalCodeGetter.getPostal(row1.streetNum, row1.streetName, row1.city)` if the input flow and schema columns are so named.

Documentation is available at
https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/8.0/studio-user-guide-open-studio-for-data-integration/creating-user-routines

Comment: Hey yeah thanks I went and did that and it worked the api was so slow though that it took 4 hours to complete 70000 rows of data

Comment: Glad to help.  Depending on your need, you might want to consider using in your job a tRESTClient component coupled to tExtractJSONFields. It'll do what your method does, perhaps with better performance.